# Why math.pi and math.e constants are written in lowercase in Python?

Tags: python, math, constants, uppercase, pep8

In most Python modules the constants are written in uppercase, i.e.:

**`datetime` module:**

- `datetime.MINYEAR`
- `datetime.MINYEAR`

**`locale` module:**

- `locale.LC_MONETARY`
- `locale.LC_TIME`
- `locale.DAY_1`

**`os` module:**

- `os.PRIO_PGRP`
- `os.PRIO_USER`

But in the `math` module, the only 2 constants that has in it are written in lowercase: 
`math.pi` and `math.e`.

This could be explained if the `math` module were a third party library, but it isn't, it's a part of the standard library.

Yes, I know that in Python there aren't authentic constants, but this is style writting is used in most modules as said by the [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)

So, why these two constants aren't written in uppercase in Python?  Are there any reason for it?

Comment: Note *"usually"*; and *"A Foolish Consistency is the Hobgoblin of Little Minds"*. Also, bear in mind that if `math` was written that way before the current style was laid out, without a really good reason to change (and break all the code already using e.g. `math.e`) it would be left alone.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In this case consistency wouldn't seem to be foolish. Probably you're right in the second part :)

Comment: My guess would be simply that `pi` and `e` are written in lowercase in mathematical equations (the pi is a small greek letter pi), so they preferred to be consistent to that.

Comment: @tobias_k I agree in the case of `e`, but `pi` in maths are written π (unicode: '\u03C0') not `pi`

Comment: @Trimax I think that most people don't have π on their keyboards, so that would be very inconvenient.

Comment: Also, `math.pi` isn't really a constant. You'll get a 32-bit version of `pi` on a 32-bit Python, and a `pi` with 64 bits of precision on a 64-bit Python.

Comment: In Python 3 you could define `π = math.pi` (it's Alt-P on OS X), but it seems like showing off!

Comment: @LukasGraf: What? Why would that be the case? Python floats are C doubles on either 32-bit or 64-bit Python, and [`math.pi`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/mathmodule.c#l70) is defined with the same precision no matter whether Python is compiled as 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 9):

[PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) was created on 05-Jul-2001, whereas these constants exist at least since 1990, as can be seen in [this initial revision](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/mathmodule.c?revision=2167&view=markup) of `math` module implementation. [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) in his comment made a good guess IMHO, that lowercase in this case seems more natural from mathematician's point of view. Another possible reason is that Python was [heavily influenced](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/01/pythons-design-philosophy.html) by the ABC programming language, in which `pi` is also lowercase ([reference](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~steven/abc/qr.html)).

Still I think you're right that this is an inconsistency with commonly accepted coding style rules (as they are nowadays), present not only in Python.

Note also that it's not the only inconsistency, [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) mentions also the `threading` module being not consistent with the guidelines in terms of *Function names*:

> mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

The obvious reason not to fix this is, as noted by [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) in his comment, is also mentioned in [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> In particular: do not break backwards compatibility just to comply with this PEP!

Probably it would be a good idea to add aliases that conform to the guidelines, as the OP have mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: The `threading` module has a lot of complexity and "Note: Starting with Python 2.6, this module provides PEP 8 compliant aliases and properties to replace the camelCase names that were inspired by Java’s threading API."  Only 2 constants aren't complex to replace or adding PEP 8 compliant aliases.

Comment: @Trimax Good point, I agree with you. However I think it would be hard to guess why it wasn't done. Perhaps it's just that nobody thought about it :)

Answer (score -2):

You could always submit a proposal to introduce uppercase aliases for `math.e`and `math.pi`.

Since in mathematics e and pi are lowercase, I suggest `math.LOWERCASE_E` and `math.LOWERCASE_PI`.